# Unable to make a private void NAME(); in C#

Tags: c#, void

So I have this code:

```
private void update();
{

}
```

In visual studio, it shows up like this:

[image]

The errors are:

Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Why does it do this? It's not in another void or anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

remove the  `;` after `private void.`

```
private void update()
{

}
```